# How to list files changed by author ordered by percentage of changed lines in git

Tags: git

I would like to see a list of all files in a repository that were changed by a given author on HEAD, along with a percentage of how much of the file's content was last modified by that author, ordered by that percentage.
For example, I'd like to see an output such as:

```
src/main/java/com/example/Hello.java (80%)
src/main/java/com/example/Constants.java (57%)
src/test/java/com/example/Hello.java (25%)
./build.gradle (15%)
```

I've already tried listing with `git whatchanged`, `git log`, but the  best I could get was simply a list of modified files. I'm really interested in the percentage that was last modified by the author.

Comment: I can start you off with `git log --stat --no-merges -n 200 --author 'Your Author Here' | grep '|' | awk '{ print $1 " " $3 }'`. This will print a non-unique list of files and the number of lines changed. you'd have to write a small script to sum up all the changes and calculate percentages. Note that you'll have to play with `awk` a bit if your filenames have spaces in them.

Comment: @root this prints the number of lines modified, but it counts both additions and removals, and also ignores other potential modifications on the files. I'm looking into sort of summing up all lines that were last modified by some user (such as in git blame) for all files